# Find a nonzero polynomial $f(X)$ with integer coefficients such that $f(\sqrt3 + \sqrt7)=0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find a nonzero polynomial $f(X)$ with integer coefficients such that $f(\sqrt3 + \sqrt7)=0$

I was thinking it might be possible using the rational roots theorem, but I've never used it with square roots, only integers. Any advice?

Comment: How would the rational roots theorem possibly apply here? It gives you restrictions on rational roots of a given polynomial, here you have neither a rational root nor a polynomial to start with...

Comment: Hint: let $x=\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{7}$. Then $x^2 = 3 + 2 \sqrt{21} + 7$. Regroup and square again.

Comment: thanks dxiv! that combined with Roby5 helped immensely!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subtle variation of @dxiv's idea

Let $x=\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{7} \Rightarrow x-\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{7}$

Now, squaring both sides, we get

$$x^2+3-2\sqrt{3}x=7 \Rightarrow x^2-4=2\sqrt{3}x$$

Again, squaring both sides, we get

$$x^4-8x^2+16=12x^2 \Rightarrow x^4-20x^2+16=0$$

Comment: This makes sense! would this trick work for similar problems? What about if had let $x-\surd7 = \surd3$ ?

Comment: @knames Yes, you would get the same answer. This would work for integer coefficients of $f(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})$ where $a,b$ are square-free naturals.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! ( will keep this in mind for future problems.

Answer (score 4):

$$\prod_{(s_1,s_2)\in\{-1,+1\}^2}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!(x-s_1\sqrt{3}-s_2\sqrt{7}) =\color{red}{x^4-20x^2+16}$$
is an element of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ that clearly vanishes at $x=\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{7}$.
 Another approach for achieving the same: we may consider the ring $\mathbb{Q}[a,b]/(a^2-3,b^2-7)$ and the powers $(a+b)^k$ for $k\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ represented with respect to the base $1,a,b,ab$. We have five vectors in a vector space with dimension four, hence a non-trivial combination of them gives the zero vector. Such a combination is associated with a polynomial (actually, the *minimal* polynomial) with integer coefficients having $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{7}$ as a root:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline & 1 & a & b & ab \\ 
\hline (a+b)^0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline (a+b)^1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\hline (a+b)^2 & 10 & 0 & 0 & 2\\
\hline (a+b)^3 & 0 & 24 & 16 & 0 \\
\hline (a+b)^4 & 184 & 0 & 0 & 40 \\\hline\end{array}$$
we may notice, by Gaussian elimination, that the last row ($k=4$) minus 20 times the third row ($k=2$) plus 16 times the first row ($k=0$) equals zero. So we recover the polynomial $x^4-20x^2+16$ and by studying the rank of the last matrix we may also prove it is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{7}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thank you! this makes sense, although I found it more complicated than Roby5's post, partly because I am incredibly rusty in algebra.

Comment: @knames: I agree it is a bit of an overkill, but it gives an idea about computing a polynomial that vanishes at $\alpha+\beta$ given a polynomial that vanishes at $\alpha$ and a polynomial that vanishes at $\beta$. I wrote this for the sake of generality.

Comment: +1... Bill D. taught me to appreciate "overkill" (and color-coded answers!)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the minimal polynomial of $x=\sqrt 3+\sqrt 7$ (you will find the same polynomial for the four possibilities $x=\pm\sqrt3\pm\sqrt7$ because of known conjugates of the first given $x$). This is squaring $$f(x)=x^4-20x^2+16$$

The answer of your question can be anyone of the infinitely many polynomials
$$f(x)g(x)$$ where $0\ne g\in \Bbb Z[x]$ (obviously $f$ has relevance!).

Comment: Your first sentence, that's similar to how roby5 did it, the known conjugates, right? And thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. (I have considered the easy Galois theory for quadratic fields and the m.p. from $x^2=10+2\sqrt{21}$ but yes, it is something similar as roby5 did but "more similar" to the first part of Jack D'Aurizio).